# PowerShell OpenLDAP query returns nothing

Tags: powershell, openldap

I'm trying to retrieve OpenLDAP 2.4 users info.
Connection and bind are OK but request return nothing.
After some investigations, I discovered that there are more than 150 000 records to import. I tried to change `$ModelQuery` size limit but it didn't change a thing.
What would be the good way to manage this?

```bsh
$HostName = "ldap.domain.com:389"
$user = 'user'

$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
$pass = [PSCredential]::($user, $Password)

$null = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices.Protocols")

$LDAPConnect = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection "$HostName"
$LDAPConnect.AuthType = [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.AuthType]::Basic
$LDAPConnect.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3

try {
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    $LDAPConnect.Credential = [PSCredential]::($user, $Password)
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
} catch {
    throw "Erreur Bind LDAP - $($_.Exception.Message)"
}

Write-Verbose "Bind LDAP réussi" -Verbose

$BaseDn = 'ou=accounts,dc=domain,dc=com'
$Scope = [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope]::Subtree
$AttrList = $null
$Filter = '(property=staff)'
$ModelQuery = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchRequest -ArgumentList $BaseDn, $Filter, $Scope, $AttrList
$ModelQuery.SizeLimit = 10

try {
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    $ModelRequest = $LDAPConnect.SendRequest($ModelQuery)
    $ModelRequest.
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
} catch {
    throw "Probleme de recherche sélection - $($_.Exception.Message)"
}

$ModelRequest.Entries | Export-Csv c:\res.csv
```

Comment: `[PSCredential]::($user, $Password)` -> `[PSCredential]::new($user, $Password)`

Comment: oups...Thank you Ansgar. Furthermore, I deleted the first one. Now, I'm trying to set up an array or list to put results in it.Hoping that it will return values.I'm not sure that modify sizelimit will be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

just add variable@() and put entries in it then pipe in csv